# Byte Buddy - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException - what is the correct defineMethod syntax?

Tags: java, code-generation, byte-buddy

I am trying to create a setter and a getter for a field using Byte Buddy.

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {

        Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("domain")
                .defineField("id", int.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)               
                .defineMethod("getId", int.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
                .make()
                .load(Sample.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();

        Object o = type.newInstance();
        Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(o.toString());       
        Method m = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getId", int.class);
        System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
}
```

In the accessing field section of the learn pages [here](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) it is stated that creating a setter and getter is trivial by using an `implementation` after defining the method and then using `FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty()`

The  `Method m = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getId", int.class);` throws the NoSuchMethodException.

What is the correct syntax for creating a getter and a setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method call should be

```
Method m = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getId");
```

`int` is the return type, and you don't have to specify the return type in the `getDeclaredMethod` call - only the argument types and the method `getId` has no arguments.